# Keep only rows until elements in DateTimeIndex are consecutively continued in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a `DateTimeIndex` that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(
        start=pd.Timestamp("2023-03-20 12:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        end=pd.Timestamp("2023-03-20 15:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        freq="15Min",
    ),
    data={
        "my_column": [
            2.0,
            1.0,
            1.0,
            3.0,
            3.0,
            3.0,
            4.0,
            4.0,
            4.0,
            2.0,
            3.0,
            3.0,
            1.0,
        ],
    },
)

df = df.drop(index=["2023-03-20 13:45:00+00:00", "2023-03-20 14:45:00+00:00"])

print(df)
```

yields:

```
                        my_column
2023-03-20 12:00:00+00:00        2.0
2023-03-20 12:15:00+00:00        1.0
2023-03-20 12:30:00+00:00        1.0
2023-03-20 12:45:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:00:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:15:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:30:00+00:00        4.0
2023-03-20 14:00:00+00:00        4.0
2023-03-20 14:15:00+00:00        2.0
2023-03-20 14:30:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 15:00:00+00:00        1.0
```

Now, I only want to keep the rows until the first "missing" consecutive element in the `DateTimeIndex` e. g. filter the `DataFrame` from `2023-03-20 12:00:00+00:00` to `2023-03-20 13:30:00+00:00`.

Is there any quick generic solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the period, you can compute the time difference between successive values using [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), then compare to the frequency and use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to flag all rows after for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
diff = df.index.to_series().diff()

out = df.loc[~diff.gt('15min').cummax()]
```

Or you can infer the frequency from the first difference:

```
out = df.loc[~diff.gt(diff.dropna().iloc[0]).cummax()]
# or
out = df.loc[~diff.gt(diff.iloc[1]).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
                           my_column
2023-03-20 12:00:00+00:00        2.0
2023-03-20 12:15:00+00:00        1.0
2023-03-20 12:30:00+00:00        1.0
2023-03-20 12:45:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:00:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:15:00+00:00        3.0
2023-03-20 13:30:00+00:00        4.0
```